# UIActivityViewControllerCompletionHandler How to?

Tags: objective-c, event-handling, cocos2d-iphone, ios6

I am trying to use the `UIActivityViewControllerCompletionHandler`  , but i dont quite get how..

I want to detect when the user finishes or dismisses this **view controller** (`UIActivityViewController`).

Anyone knows how?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```c
typedef void (^UIActivityViewControllerCompletionHandler)
    (NSString *activityType, BOOL completed);
```

The second parameter of the completion handler tells you whether the user dismissed the controller. If they dismissed the controller, `completed` will be set to `NO`.

There's more details in [the completion handler's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011976-CH1-SW6).

Comment: Hey dude, how can I know whether I have post successfully? Because even the post is failed indeed, the "completed" remains also Yes/1 – Paradise

Answer (score 70):

Here's how you show a sharing dialog and set its completion handler

```
NSArray *imageArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:shareImage];

UIActivityViewController *sharing = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:imageArray applicationActivities:nil];

[sharing setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed) {
    NSLog(@"completed dialog - activity: %@ - finished flag: %d", activityType, completed);
}];

[self presentViewController:sharing animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Hey dude, how can I know whether I have post successfully? Because even the post is failed indeed, the "completed" remains also Yes/1

Comment: This approach is deprecated in iOS8.

Answer (score 25):

With iOS 8 `completionHandler` is *deprecated*, so you will want to provide alternative `completionWithItemsHandler`. It also allows to handle if extension modified data you set (say Photo extension). See [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIActivityViewControllerCompletionWithItemsHandler)

```
    UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[text, URL, image] applicationActivities:nil];
    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeAirDrop, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList];

    // check if new API supported
    if ([activityViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(completionWithItemsHandler)]) {
        activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = ^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed, NSArray *returnedItems, NSError *activityError) {
            // When completed flag is YES, user performed specific activity
        };
    } else {
        activityViewController.completionHandler = ^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed) {
            // When completed flag is YES, user performed specific activity
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5:**

```
func showShareOf(url: URL, title: String) {
    let shareItems: [Any] = ["\(title)\n", url]
    let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: shareItems, applicationActivities: nil)
    activityVC.completionWithItemsHandler = doneSharingHandler
    self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@objc func doneSharingHandler(activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType?, completed: Bool, _ returnedItems: [Any]?, error: Error?) {
    if (!completed) { return }
    // If here, log which activity occurred
    print("Shared activity: \(activityType)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### You can use completionWithItemsHandler

Here is the code in Objective-C. Please translate it into Swift accordingly.

```
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[text] applicationActivities:nil];

activityVC.completionWithItemsHandler  = ^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed, NSArray *returnedItems, NSError *error){
          
   if (completed) {
             
        NSLog(@"Shared by activity %@", activityType);

    } else {
        NSLog(@"ShareSheet was closed");
    }
   
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"An Error Occured: %@, %@", error.localizedDescription, error.localizedFailureReason);
             
    }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

For Swift, this one works for me...

```
    // Configure UIActivityViewController
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypeAirDrop,
        UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
        UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
        UIActivityTypePrint,
        UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard]

    // Show UIActivityViewController
    presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    // Define completion handler
    activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = doneSharingHandler

...

func doneSharingHandler(activityType: String!, completed: Bool, returnedItems: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) {

    // Return if cancelled
    if (!completed) {
        return
    }
    // If here, log which activity occurred
    println("Shared video activity: \(activityType)")
}
```

Comment: could u add a doneSharingHandler as a block declaration?