# How to know what activityType is used?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm using UIActivityViewController for social sharing purposes, and I need to log what social network has being used. I know that I should use `typedef void (^UIActivityViewControllerCompletionHandler)(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed);` and activityType will give me the string that i need, but I don't know how to implement syntactically. Please, can anyone help me get the direction, I'm very newbie.

Comment: Look there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12552414/uiactivityviewcontrollercompletionhandler-how-to and check the `activityType` in the block.

Comment: @Larme thank you for quick response, I've seen this thread, but I should pay some attention to answer below the accepted. Sorry for disturbance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, for those who need syntax on how to get `activityType`

```
[yourUIActivityViewController setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed) {
        NSLog(@"activity: %@ isCompleted: %d", activityType, completed);
}];
```

based on very [helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12683313/1657730) and quick response of @Larme